# How do I disable automatic updates of Google Chrome on Mac OS X?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, macos

I rebooted my machine (Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6 15G31) and re-opened Google Chrome version 69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit). It took me to the newly-updated version of the browser. When I went to Chrome -> Help -> About Google Chrome, I accidentally clicked on the "Automatically update for all users across all devices" line, and it changed to "Automatic updates are turned on". I don't want to automatically update Chrome across all of my devices. I can't see any place to turn this setting off. What do I do??

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Depends how you setup auto update. If it's for you only:

[image]

, then just:

```
sudo chmod -R 000 ~/Library/Google
```

To revert it back:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ~/Library/Google
```

If it's for all users:

[image]

Then you can change permission as above for `/Library/Google/` or even remove it completely.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Google/
```

After you will see 
[image]
or 
[image]

depending on choosing method.

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome downloads updates automatically from https://tools.google.com/service/update2.
Spoofing a DNS record of the respective host will prevent the updates from being located.

Add the following mapping to the hosts file `/etc/hosts`:

```
0.0.0.0 tools.google.com
```

Shell script [chrome_update_block.sh](https://gist.github.com/sshymko/e062db78369346917a16ca3da09db74f) automates this configuration.

Chrome will no longer be able to fetch updates after restart:
[image]

**Caution!** [GA Opt-out](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout) and other online tools on the same domain will become inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this should work to disable background updates:

`` launchctl disable user/`id -u`/com.google.keystone.system.agent ``

Answer (score 0):

I generally approve software auto updates, but Chrome  dev ran out of OKR and adds crap features like hide www and protocol and there's no way to revert it in v79 and above, and removed use tools like `chrome://net-internals`

To disable update

```
chmod 000 '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks'
```

To disable the updater:

```
sudo chmod -R  000  ~/Library/Google/
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey bro unfortunately google hided it so deep
For mac os try to find google folder in library which contains chrome update folder just empty this folder and then lock it with get info ( right click on upchrome update folder then get info n hit locked)
If u can't find it so try to use clean my mac app just open it n hit uninstaller n then mark chrome so u will find all chrome files n folders just mark on chrome update folder n choose reveal in finder n do the above steps
I hope that will help

Comment: People are more likely to read your answer if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](https://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your answer to add paragraphs and bullet points ... and please don't use txt speak.

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal and enter

```
defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0
```

Comment: this used to work, but not anymore.